# Can deleted data from outlook 2013 inbox be recovered from server end?

Tags: outlook

is it possible for the data to be restored from the server end when items have been deleted from deleted items folder in outlook 2013?

-Exchange server 2010
-user's machine is running outlook 2013

Comment: Have you asked the other team? What mail server are you using?

Comment: speaking to the exchange team, they claim there's no chance of restoring the data. They've just upgraded from exchange 2003 to exchange 2010 and claim Exchange 2010 does not have the functionality to restore data - of course we are convinced this is not true

Comment: It sounds like you're not really suffering from a technical problem. I would suggest [reading up here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/f8bc327c-8ca9-4473-a4ac-73e739de77bc/search-and-recover-emails-on-exchange-2010-that-is-deleted-by-user-maliciously-using-outlook?forum=exchangesvradmin). However you probably should be talking this out with the exchange team, not a technical Q&A site. (As this question is pretty much off-topic here)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it's a business problem rather than a technical problem (sorry!).

Comment: i don't see how this is a business problem, its a question of knowledge-share and I've edited the question to be direct. just because I've given a little background as to why the question was asked doesn't mean I don't want to know the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe.  How would we know , given that you've told us exactly nothing about your Exchange environment, beyond the fact that you have one?

[You should probably check the Outlook deleted items folder first anyway](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Restore-deleted-items-in-Outlook-cd9dfe12-8e8c-4a21-bbbf-4bd103a3f1fe?CorrelationId=62c38e1e-fdc4-4341-a44f-b73526008258&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).